# Probability of drawing a heart and an ace (in that order)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Please let me know if my reasoning is correct: Assuming no replacement, the event space of drawing a heart first and then an ace is partitioned into the following disjoint events:

1. Ace of heart, Non-heart ace (Probability = $\frac{1}{52}.\frac{3}{51}$)
2. Heart but not ace, ace of heart (Probability = $\frac{12}{52}.\frac{1}{51}$)
3. Heart but not ace, Non-heart ace (Probability = $\frac{12}{52}.\frac{3}{51}$)

So the probability of drawing a heart first and then an ace is the sum of the probabilities of the 3 events.

Sum of events $1, 2, 3$ is $\frac{51}{(52)(51)} = \frac{1}{52}$ So this is the probability of drawing a head first and then an ace...

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it isn't the sum.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the sum? Are the events not disjoint?

Comment: I am confused as well, I thought it was a perfectly solved problem.

Comment: nevermind, I read it wrong. It looks good :)

Comment: ok thanks! I just thought the answer looks too neat to be correct! I just can't really visualize that its the same probability as just drawing any card in the deck once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is correct.  Although your events 2 and 3 could have been combined into the event "heart but not ace, ace (probability = $\frac{12}{52}\cdot \frac{4}{51}$)".

Comment: To help see why it is the same probability as drawing a single card (1/52), consider that there are 52 possible combinations of value and suit, all equally likely.

Comment: Re the above comment, what if the question were drawing two hearts and an ace in sequence ?

Comment: In that case, there are 4*4*13 combinations of suit-suit-value, but they are *not* all equally likely.